# Android Studio Slow Debugging on Device

Tags: android, performance, debugging, dalvik

All was well until very recently when I noticed that debugging has become very slow. I do not recall any drastic changes that would cause this.

UI Navigation has a noticeable lag and network operations take forever. This is somewhat remedied if I reboot the phone and restart Android Studio/ADB.

App behaves fine when running in normal mode.

I'm using Dalvik runtime, on Android 4.4.2. I have not used ART.

Any advice on how to address this?

Comment: side note: using Android V4 Support library in the project, although don't see how this should impact debugging, but FYI.

Comment: Same here I am using a real phone and it literally takes minutes to go from one activity to the next even though I have only 1 breakpoint.

Answer (score 20):

Check your breakpoints in Debug bookmark (button "View Breakpoints"), if there are many breakpoints which you forgot delete in the past this may slow you debugger. In my case deleting all breakpoints fix the problem.

Comment: I had accidentally left a breakpoint on a var initialization. Removed it and it runs perfectly smooth now, thanks!

Comment: In Android Studio 4.1.1, we can also disable breakpoints by unchecking them which too helped speed up debugging for me. This way breakpoints need not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I had such an experience before and it was due to a custom library that I had attached to my project, I still don't know how these two were related but after removing the library it worked like a charm.
See what has been added to your project recently, maybe it help you too.