# Running application from Android Studio debug became slow

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, debugging, adb

Running apps in debug mode has become noticeably slower in recent days. There are several posts about slow debug performance but no clear explanation on how to remedy the problem. The project doesn't have any breakpoints.

[Android Studio 2.2.1: Slow Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227208/android-studio-2-2-1-slow-debugging)
[android studio debugger verry slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390948/android-studio-debugger-verry-slow)
[Android Studio Slow Debugging on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532999/android-studio-slow-debugging-on-device)

A signed .aab file uploaded to PlayStore works normally. Also, using "bundletool" to convert a signed .aab to .apks works as expected. An unsigned .apk doesn't work.

The problem is pertinent to both physical and virtual devices.

Similar behavior is observed by my colleagues.

The problem started a few days ago with Giraffe 2022.3.1 and wasn't remedied in 2023.2.1.

2023.2.1 Canary 11
Gradle Plugin: 8.3.0-alpha11
Gradle: 8.4-rc-2
Java: VERSION_1_8

Comment: I observe exactly the same things.And this is particulary visible on m'y pixel 6a. (Not so much on other devices). Splashscreen loads twice, ...

Comment: Same thing here. As a temporary solution, you can launch app via "profile app with low overhead": you can directly launch APK without debugger so you can at least use your app.

Comment: @FlexeiPrata may you clarify your approach? Do you just build a signed APK or something else?

Comment: I do not know how to fix the issue, but I have a quick workaround to be able to test app directly from the studio: "profile 'app' with low overhead" removes embedded debugger that causes the slow debug performance problem. The button is located on the top bar (3 dots).
Hope that Google will notice soon this issue

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with actually debugging the app / attaching debugger. Running the app while in debug variant is all it takes to become extremely slow. Workaround by @Flexei Prata works.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Android Studio from automatically opening the profiler when using the workaround?

Comment: Actually, I found if I add "buildTypes {debug {debuggable false}}" to module build.gradle it works normally.

Comment: In Android Studio (Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2) the "profile 'app' with low overhead" option is located under the RUN menu item.

Comment: Is your device Android14? We meet similar question in Android 14 with debuggable app https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/311251587

Answer (score 0):

My bedug app cause "Application not responding" and the user chooses to "close" the app instead of "wait". While release app is faster and no problem.

Answer (score -2):

When the following is added to the module build.gradle it works as expected

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```